# Why was Gotham City moved to New York City in The Dark Knight Rises?

Tags: the-dark-knight-rises, film-location

*The Dark Knight* was [shot in Chicago](http://www.movie-locations.com/movies/d/DarkKnight.html).

[image]

And so was [*Batman Begins*](http://www.movie-locations.com/movies/b/batmanbegins.html).

But *The Dark Knight Rises* is clearly shot in New York City.

Why was Gotham moved to a new city for the last part of the trilogy?

Comment: Would it have to do with wanting to show Gotham as an island, thus utilizing Manhattan?

Comment: hm, thats probably a reasonable explanation, as Chicago has Bridges but is not Island (which is crucial for the plot). But for Nolan it is so strange to just flip a complete city and therefore change the atmosphere of film in a trilogy.

Comment: True, but then Gotham in Dark Knight looked totally different to Gotham in Batman Begins too.

Comment: But the Transition from Batman Begins to Dark Knight didn't seem so drastic somehow.

Comment: "The Dark Knight Rises" was shot, in large part, in Pittsburgh, too...not just NY.

Comment: because new york gave them better tax incentives

Comment: Welcome to the site. As it stands, your answer is very opinion based. Do you have anything to back this up, or are you just being flippant? If you do have facts  please post about them and include links.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From interviews with director Christopher Nolan, it would appear that the goal was to create a non-specific setting (the film was actually shot in Pittsburgh and LA as well as New York and New Jersey), that felt both "operatic" and real.

From an interview with [James Rocchi](http://social.entertainment.msn.com/movies/blogs/the-hitlist-blogpost.aspx?post=8d70cd56-4f69-47c7-94d3-907dc245b8c0) at MSN Entertainment:

> **MSN Movies:** You knew you were doing a third film.  Is the pressure to do things bigger, better -- is that from the studio? Is it from the
>   audience? Or is it that all from you? Are you the person saying,
>   "Let's do more with this"?
>
> **Christopher Nolan:** Well, I was trying to push filmmaking from the point of view of the audience.  I'm trying to make a film that I would
>   want to go see on a Friday night and lay down ten dollars or what have
>   you and be thrilled and moved by or whatever.  And that's what was the
>   impulse, and so when you know you're dealing with characters the
>   audience have a relationship with, you're asking the audience to come
>   back to Gotham City.  So you feel a huge creative responsibility to
>   give them a reason to come back to Gotham City.

From an interview with [Emanuel Levy](http://www.emanuellevy.com/review/dark-knight-rises-interview-with-director-nolan/):

> For the first time, three separate cities provided locations and
>   backdrops for Gotham City, with scenes filmed in Pittsburgh, Los
>   Angeles, and the city sometimes nicknamed Gotham, New York.
>
> Nolan offers, “When you look back on the films, you can see the world
>   we’re living in reflected, but we don’t want to be specific about it.
>   We just come at the stories from the point of view of what concerns
>   us. What gives us fear? What gives us hope? What would require a hero
>   of Batman’s stature to rise up in our world?”

And from an interview with [Alex Tucker](http://tvfilmnews.com/christopher-nolan-the-dark-knight-rises-interview/) at TV-Film-News:

> **‘The Dark Knight Rises’ magnifies and resolves the main themes of the
>   trilogy, one of which is mythmaking, and the discussion of the Batman
>   Gotham needs.
>
> Christopher Nolan:** One of the things I’ve enjoyed about working with
>   these characters is that they have the potential to be topical. And
>   the reason for that is they’re not real. It’s not real life. You’re
>   dealing with a heightened reality. You’re not dealing with Chicago or
>   New York; you’re dealing with Gotham City. And that gives you a very
>   interesting world to be able to play with in a very heightened way, in
>   a very operatic way.

And some practical reasoning from the [Chicago Tribune](http://www.chicagotribune.com/entertainment/ct-ae-0722-borrelli-chicago-gotham-20120720,0,7522757.column):

> **Chicago-less Gotham**
>
> Chicago, don't take this personally, but: "The Dark Knight Rises," the
>   first of Nolan's Batman movies not to be shot here, was wise not to
>   shoot here this time. For variety's sake, sure. But also, a better
>   reason: A quick shot of the Chicago skyline screams money and
>   prosperity. A quick shot of Pittsburgh, where a lot of the film was
>   shot, reveals working-class areas within yearning range of gleaming
>   skyscrapers. You'd have to find a pretty wide lens before you could
>   hold the poor of Chicago and the rich of Chicago within the same
>   frame. True, in "Rises" the Manhattan skyline is liberally mixed in;
>   all the better to play up the 1-percenters. (Still, two nods to
>   Chicago do sneak in, sorta: Batman swings by a historic neighborhood
>   named "Old Town," and those Gotham license plates are hilariously
>   reminiscent of Illinois license plates.)

Answer (score 0):

In Batman Begins, it was built mostly from scratch, but dark knight and dark knight rises,were filmed in real, existing cities like Chicago, New York, and London, England

Comment: Hi anux! Welcome to Movies SE. Got a link to support this?